# how to Natural sort on Elasticsearch 2.4.4

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

sorry for I'm not good at English. I want to sort naturally on elasticsearch 2.4.4.

For example, with these documents:

```
{ name: "Bob: 3 points" }
{ name: "Bob: 10 points" }
{ name: "Bob: 2 points" }
```

When ES sorts on the "name" field, the documents are returned in this order:

```
{ name: "Bob: 10 points" }
{ name: "Bob: 2 points" }
{ name: "Bob: 3 points" }
```

How can we get ES to return the documents in the following order?

```
{ name: "Bob: 2 points" }
{ name: "Bob: 3 points" }
{ name: "Bob: 10 points" }
```

I found a natural sort plugin on github: [jprante/elasticsearch-analysis-naturalsort](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-analysis-naturalsort)
but my elasticsearch version is not supported by this plugin. 
Please help me! T
hank everyone!

Comment: Why don't save your data in two fields like `{"name":"Bob", "points": 3}` etc? That way you could sort on the `points` field.